# Remove completely all kind of encoding/default/automatic encoding on jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, character-encoding

Are we able remove completely all kind of encoding/default encoding on jquery ajax call ?
Fyr, javascript code :

```
function callServer()
    {
        debugger;
        var uncompressed64Data = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wCEAA0JCgsKCA0LCgsODg0PEyAVExISEyccHhcgLikxMC4pLSwzOko+MzZGNy"
        alert(uncompressed64Data.length);
        var compressed = LZString.compressToUTF16(uncompressed64Data);
        //alert('compressed Length : ' + compressed.length);
        var pCurrentPage = 'Prabhu';
        /* var formData = "img="+compressed+"&CurrentPage="+pCurrentPage.toString(); */
        jQuery.ajax({
            url : "/RegisterServlet_2/servlet/Register",
            type : "POST",
            contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-15",
            data : {
                img : compressed,
                CurrentPage : pCurrentPage,
            },
            cache : false,
            async : false,
            success : function()
            {
            },
            error : function()
            {
            }
        });
    }
```

Fyr, above call I make and I can able to see the request body always encoded. As per application I dont want encoding and the chars should reach the server without any encoding?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of content type.

Normally when a `<form>` uses the **HTTP method POST then the form values are URL Encoded and placed in the body of the reqeust**. The content type header looks like this:

```
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

You can simply use different content type

```
content-type: application/json
```

or

```
content-type: text/xml
```

I f you don't want json/xml, use plaine text

```
content-type: text/plain
```

Comment: Tried already!!.  See, if we that Jquery by default encode! we can see that in browser dev tool. the problem with encoding is the request body increased and so the transfer bandwidth